Tikz: Wrapping labels in a node on a tree
I'm building a tree in Tikz.  The labels are too long and are not responding to the double backslash.  It should be clear from the code where I want the word wrapping.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[ rectangle, draw, color=red] {Title}
        [child anchor=north]    
        child  {node (Inv) {SubTitle}  }
        child  {node (Sel) {SecTitle}
            child {node (LB) {SubSub \\ Title} }
            child {node (PT) {SubSubSec  \\ Title}  }
             }
        child {node (Dev) {{Third \\ Title}}  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Any suggestions, please?
The following were not helpful:
Auto word wrapping in a node in TikZ?
This is automatic word wrapping.  I want to choose.
Looking for a solution to automatically wrap text in `\node`  Again Automatic word warping.  I want to choose where to break and then fit a box or bubble around it.

You could use a tabular

\\ line break works if you set the align key. Add, as example
\tikzset{
  every node/.style={align=center}
}

Full example:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={align=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle, draw, color=red] {Title}
  [child anchor=north]
  child  {node (Inv) {SubTitle}  }
  child  {node (Sel) {SecTitle}
    child {node (LB) {SubSub\\ Title} }
    child {node (PT) {SubSubSec\\   Title}  }
  }
  child {node (Dev) {Third\\  Title}  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


